# which is better apache or tomcat apache for webservice of java application..?

Tags: java, wcf, web-services, apache, tomcat6

I have Used Tomcat Apache to use my java desktop application as a webservice.so is that good option Or i need to use apache server to make my java application as a webservice?

Wht i want is after my webservice made with apachetomcat ..can i call that webservice with wcf or desktop application of .net?

wcf service -> call webservice of java application(using apache tomcat) ->execute java application on server->and return resutl to wcf service

wcf service has function as below

call Javaapplication();

and throught that can i invoke java programm on server?

is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking at Apache products, Axis is the tool for web services.  And to that, I would look at [Axis2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/).  But, I would encourage you to look at the variety of options out there and select the best for you.

Answer (score 2):

Apache is an http server. Tomcat is a Java EE environment which includes the ability to function as an http server.

Apache alone won't run your Java application. In many cases, Tomcat will be enough, but in higher-volume situations, you may want to use Apache and Tomcat together.

Other than that, it looks like you need to find a good tutorial on Java EE and Web Services, like, perhaps, [this one by Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/)